# How to change NERDTree plugin window continuously

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

So, for example in `tmux` you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and move the separation line with the arrow keys.

Is there any way to do this with NERDTree without using a longer, somewhat discrete command every time?

Comment: This might be sacrilegious, but have you thought about using the mouse? `:set mouse=a`. See `:h 'mouse'`

Comment: Yes, I have, but was interested with the keyboard for.. you know..reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vim you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> to decrease and increase window width, respectively. Add comfortable mappings for you, I use the arrow keys, as follows:

```
nnoremap <Up>    :resize +2<CR>
nnoremap <Down>  :resize -2<CR>
nnoremap <Left>  :vertical resize +2<CR>
nnoremap <Right> :vertical resize -2<CR>
```

Also, I enjoy this little snippet to create a useful quick resize toggle shortcut within NERDTree:

```
function! s:SID()
    if ! exists('s:sid')
        let s:sid = matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '<SNR>\zs\d\+\ze_SID$')
    endif
    return s:sid
endfunction
let s:SNR = '<SNR>'.s:SID().'_'

call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
    \ 'key': 'w',
    \ 'callback': s:SNR.'toggle_width',
    \ 'quickhelpText': 'Toggle window width' })

function! s:toggle_width()
    let l:max = 0
    for l:z in range(1, line('$'))
        let l:len = len(getline(l:z))
        if l:len > l:max
            let l:max = l:len
        endif
    endfor
    exe 'vertical resize '.(l:max == winwidth('.') ? g:NERDTreeWinSize : l:max)
endfunction
```

With this, you can press <kbd>w</kbd> on NERDTree buffer to toggle width resize, I find it quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found these more intuitive and useful after trying Rafi's answer

```
nnoremap <Up>    <C-w>+
nnoremap <Down>  <C-w>-
nnoremap <Left>  <C-w><
nnoremap <Right> <C-w>>
```